# Django - Access nested Related Field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have 3 models, `Province`, `District`, `Commune`.

And model has fields somethings like this:

```
Province hasMany District

District hasMany Commune
```

I want to access `Province` model from `Commune` through `District`. How can I achieve it?

**My models**

```
class Province(models.Model):
    name_eng = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name_kh = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class District(models.Model):
    province = models.ForeignKey(
        Province, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="district")
    name_eng = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name_kh = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Commune(models.Model):
    district = models.ForeignKey(
        District, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="commune")
    name_eng = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name_kh = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**And my ModelViewset:**

```
class CommuneFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
   province = filters.CharFilter(field_name='province__name_kh', lookup_expr='contains')
   district = filters.CharFilter(field_name='district__name_kh', lookup_expr='contains')

   class Meta:
       model = Commune
       fields = ['district', 'province']

class CommuneViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Commune.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommuneSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = CommuneFilterSet
    ordering_fields = '__all__'
    search_fields = [
        'name_kh',
        'name_eng'
    ]
```

Between, I use [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html). Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
class CommuneFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
   province = filters.CharFilter(field_name='district__province__name_kh', lookup_expr='contains')
   # rest of the code
```

Comment: thanks for reply. let me try first, i'll let u know if it work. :)